# S3api CLI Put Command Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm using AWS CLI to apply ACL policy to an object in S3, this is the command I have used

aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket XXXX --key XXXX  --acl bucket-owner-full-control --grant-read uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers

This command gives an error in return

**An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the PutObjectAcl operation: Specifying both Canned ACLs and Header Grants is not allowed**

How to apply both Canned and Header Grants to an object ?

I tried by giving only Canned ACL first time (**aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket XXXX --key XXXX  --acl bucket-owner-full-control**) and it applied ,but when I ran second time (**aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket XXXX --key XXXX --grant-read uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers by excluding canned ACL**) and including Header Grants changes got overridden. It was including only Header Grants

Can you please help me out on this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, either you have to use Canned ACL or the Header grants. 
You can include email address of bucket owner to grant full control and for others read access.

I mean include the bucket owner details run the command something like below as stated in AWS documentation example.

aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket MyBucket --key file.txt --grant-full-control emailaddress=user1@example.com,emailaddress=user2@example.com --grant-read uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers

See the Note in AWS documentation.

Note
You can either use a canned ACL or specify access permissions explicitly. You cannot do both.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

Comment: Thanks Usman. Seems like we can do it only from Console not from CLI. Yes, I was able to either of them not both of them.